# Keep View Controller Out of Navigation Stack

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Have looked everywhere for this but cannot seem to find an answer.

I have various login view controllers, which are not part of a navigation controller and after login the user will the proceed inside the application, which from the this point on will all be added to the navigation stack when shown. However, I would like to return to the login screen upon logout. I am having two issues here, if I use a push segue to the login screen it is added to the navigation stack which I do not want to happen. However, if I unwind or present the login screen modally I seem to lose all of the animation that I had setup for transitioning and on the login screen.

Ideally, what I would like to happen is I can close/clear the navigation stack and return to the normal view hierarchy for the login phases and only return to the navigation controller upon login again.

Does anyone have any idea how this is possible? Sorry for the long explanation and thanks for your time.

Comment: why cant you present your Application view modally onto loginview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to do this, depending on  how you want it to look / the app you're trying to build. One approach I like is to present the navigation stack on top of the login view, or a main view controller which loads the login view / other views as needed.  Then when you log out you can just dismiss the view controller.

Comment: If I present the navigation stack on top of the login view, how do I dismiss the navigation stack in order to return to the login view? Thanks for your help, appreciated!

Comment: dismissViewController:animated: from any view controller. This will dismiss the entire stack that was presented unless the view controller that you call it from was presented on top of that.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go later tonight and let you know how it goes. Thanks again.